# Cross-domain request with jQuery and JSON not working in Internet Explorer (security issue?)

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I wanted to use Ajax to make a request, but when I realized that the domains were different, I decided to use JSON instead.

The code:

#### Main PHP file (script code)

```
$(".name").click(function(){
    //Get information
    var id = $(this).attr("id").substring(1);

    jQuery.getJSON("https:/otherdomain.com/makereq.php?id="+id+"&callback=?",
    function(data) {
         alert("id: " + data.id);
         return false;
    });
});
```

#### Makereq PHP file

```
$jsonData = array('id'=>$_GET['id']);
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($jsonData) . ');';
```

That works fine in Firefox. I get the data and the alert displays the id sent and received. But in Internet Explorer, a security error appears saying that the content has been blocked and the data is not received. In Chrome, it does not work neither.

Why is that happening or what am I doing wrong? Is there any solution to send and receive data without browser errors/alerts from the other domain?

Comment: Are you scraping the page for content or are you fetching json encoded data from the other server?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can't be done this way. Try to use a bridge PHP file on your domain that read other hosts content with [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL). That will works for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [jQuery page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) on `getJSON`. The section on **JSONP** is what you're after as you're trying to use data with a callback on a cross domain request.

`getJSON()` won't work here. What you want to do is write a function using the name of the callback and actually load data returned by your php file as a javascript file.

```
<script src="https:/otherdomain.com/makereq.php?id=1&callback=callBack"></script>

<script>
    callBack(data) {
       [do stuff...]
    }
</script>
```